# How to start an OS process in Elixir

Tags: elixir

What's the best way to start an OS process in Elixir?

I'd expect to be able to pass different parameters to it on start, 
capture its PID and then kill it.

Comment: Also check into System.cmd

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci System.cmd doesn't seem to work for me on windows

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use Ports to achieve this:

```
defmodule Shell do
  def exec(exe, args) when is_list(args) do
    port = Port.open({:spawn_executable, exe}, [{:args, args}, :stream, :binary, :exit_status, :hide, :use_stdio, :stderr_to_stdout])
    handle_output(port)
  end

  def handle_output(port) do
    receive do
      {^port, {:data, data}} ->
        IO.puts(data)
        handle_output(port)
      {^port, {:exit_status, status}} ->
        status
    end
  end
end

iex> Shell.exec("/bin/ls", ["-la", "/tmp"])
```

Comment: where do you use the `args`?

Comment: Oh wow, somehow forgot to add that in my example module. You just pass args: args, in the options. I'll update the code sample.

Comment: @bitwalker after checking on elixir-lang google group, **[Porcelain](http://porcelain.readthedocs.org/en/v1.1.1/)** seems like the best option for me to go with

Comment: It's worth noting that Porcelain uses Ports under the covers. It's definitely the way to go if you plan on using Ports, but it's important to know how to work at the lower level too :).